# Learning a specific functional form with machine learning

Tags: function, machine-learning, math, neural-network

Suppose I have only three independent features (x, y, z) as the input to some machine learning routine (e.g. neural network). From some domain knowledge, I know that the output o(x, y, z) must have the specific functional form

o(x, y, z) = f(x)*g(y)*g(z)

where the g(.) are the same function. The details of f(.) and g(.) are not known beforehand. Given that there is no upper limit on the sample size, is it possible to incorporate such a functional form (or in general, any specific functional form) into the machine learning routine?

Comment: yes, but if you know the functional form why bothering using neural network?

Comment: @furcifer because I don’t know what f(.) and g(.) actually are. All I know is that the output has the form of the product described above.

Comment: If you don't know them how are going to train a model? How are you going to get the labels or answers?

Comment: @furcifer the label can be obtained by some other means, which is very expensive.

Comment: if labels can be found, then neural network can be trained. But, you have to put more details. Update the question with - 1. How many samples can you manage? 2. Is there any temporal relations between the features? 3. Any other features? 4. How much error is tolerable etc.

Comment: Essentially two ways to do this: you can assume `f` and `g` have a parametric representation and then estimate the parameters, or you have to non-parametric methods such as kernel estimation. Do you know anything at all about `f` and `g`, for example if they are supposed to be probability distributions (non-negative and integrate to 1)?

Comment: @Joni thank you for your suggestion. I don’t know much about f and g, except that f is a decaying function with respect to x. With kernel methods, can you do the product of three kernels to incorporate the functional form?